# Switch + TimeSpan

Tags: c#

How may I use the `Switch` statement together with the `TimeSpan`?

```
switch (myTimeSpan)
{
    case TimeSpan.Minutes:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
        break;
    case TimeSpan.Hours:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
    case TimeSpan.Seconds:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
}
```

**Edit - Added answer**

C#7 can handle `Switch` statements with pattern matching

```
    switch(DateTime.Now-lastDate) {
        case var t when t.Days>720:
            changefreq="never";
            break;
        case var t when t.Days>365:
            changefreq="yearly";
            break;
        case var t when t.Days>180:
            changefreq="monthly";
            break;
        case var t when t.Days>30:
            changefreq="weekly";
            break;
        default:
            changefreq="daily";
            break;
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt make sense what you are trying to do here. TimeSpan is not Switch-able

Comment: Small hint: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Programming-For-Absolute-Beginner/dp/1931841160

Comment: Well, did you try this? What did it tell you? MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.100).aspx tells us that the thing following `case` must be a constant expression, which you have not provided. Switch is only really useful for reducing the syntax of `if (var == const1){ } else if (var == const2) {} else if (var = =const3) {} ...` and not in the case of `if (var < const1) {} else if (var > const2) {} ...`

Answer (score 13):

I guess what you're trying to do is something like this

```
if (span.TotalSeconds >= 60 * 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hours");
}
else if (span.TotalSeconds >= 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine("minutes");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("seconds");
}
```

Comment: +1 for trying to help instead of just voting to close and/or downvoting.